How can I increase my counter and have it persist across scenes and runtime
How can I make the muon counter "0/15" from the stage selection scene number go up when the player object touches the muon game object which you can only touch them in the stage scenes and not only that, how can I save the number on like like if you interacted with 3 muon objects from a stage scene, it becomes "3/15" how can I save it  when you exit the game so you don't have to restart everything to do it all over agian? we can also talk about it more on discord if you have it
https://gdl.space/aguxobupov.cs Muon object where the player interacts which would cause the number from other scenes like the stage select to go up
https://gdl.space/izumaxitiz.cpp counter in the play game which at first were used for coin counting
https://gdl.space/rifuwociwo.cs Muon counter which counts how many muons from each stage you have rescued
enter image description here
enter image description here

Can you share a minimal reproducible example without personal privacy  through GitHub?

what do you mean Fei Xu? I'm not showing any personal privacy through git hub

You may misunderstand something, I mean that it is difficult to determine where the problem is through the description you provided , you should share an example so that others can help you, just advice @Linedol trainer channel gammin

Does e.g. this tutorial help?

I hope you already solved this but in case you haven't yet. Unity has a feature called scriptable objects which allows you to create an object that exists outside of the scene and can hold specific values. Even if the game stops or you change scenes.
The following link has a tutorial about it that helps explain it in more depth as well as provided example code.
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html
Hope this helps!
